# Differential Equation and Limits

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

I'm trying to solve this question:

> If the solution of  $y''-y'-2y=0$, which satisfies $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=m$, is limited in the interval $[0,\infty]$, then $m$ equals to:
>
> $a)-1\qquad b)-2\qquad c)\;0\qquad d)\;1\qquad e)\;2 $

Ok, I found the solution:

$$Y(t) = \frac{(m+1)}{3}e^{2t}+\frac{(2-m)}{3}e^{-t}$$

But now, how can I find $m$? I tried to compute the limit with $t\to\infty$ but I don't get how to solve it. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: $y$ is bounded in the interval.  Consider the $e^{2t}$ term.  What has to happen to keep it from "running away" as $t$ becomes large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term $e^{2t}$ blows up in the limit t goes to $\infty$.

To prevent that from happening, you ought to make that first term zero, ie set m=-1.